# PHP - how to Limit Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a project for class.  I am working with an array and need to limit the size of the array to have no more than 1,000,000 numeric keys.  I also need to restrict the element to be no more than 5,000,000.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: PHP does not support this sort of limitation as far as I know.

Comment: Just use a `if` or two, no?

Comment: The only way you can do this is by checking before you create or append to an array with if.

Comment: Look at `SplFixedArray` http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php

Comment: If you've already got the array and are trying to shrink it, you can use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to assign items 0-999999 to a new array (or back to itself).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SplFixedArray` For example:

```
$array = new SplFixedArray(1000000);
```

Here's the manual page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php

Answer (score 0):

An array having 1 million keys and values(Useless + too much memory). Anyways, you can do this by using this...

Use SplFixedArray() for this.

```
$array = new SplFixedArray(1000000);
$array[0] = '1st Element';
Uptil.....
$array[999999] = '999999th Element'
```

and the same for 5000000

```
$newarray = new SplFixedArray(5000000);
$newarray[0] = '1st Element';
Uptil.....
$newarray[4999999] = '4999999th Element'
```